# Dynamic Github Actions Steps

Tags: github-actions

The following shows what the Github Actions tab displays for a typical build:

[image: output]

The Build step actually has a number of sub-steps, but I do not want to use Github Actions as a scripting language *just* to be able to have each sub-step discreetly displayed.  Is there any sort of magic that Github Actions provides to signal that you wish the visualization of the build to show a discrete step (i.e. a "dynamic step")?

I'm hoping for something like the following which would cause the creation of discrete result nodes in the output of the Github Actions build visualization:

```
- name: Dynamic Steps
  run |
     echo "###github-action-step: Step 1"
     echo "###github-action-step: Step 2"
     echo "###github-action-step: Step 3"
```

Comment: I love that GH decided to invent yet-another YAML thinger and then went that extra mile and made their YAML thinger Turning complete. (sarcasm) https://github.com/community/community/discussions/17330

Comment: (Not sarcasm) GH Actions stink of some product manager's fever dream about capturing -- read "locking in" -- developers.

Answer (score 3):

Something close to that can be achieved by skipping steps and/or dynamically setting the steps name.

i.e. I'm using like this to customize the tab message on GH actions:

```yaml
      - name: "Pulling existing Docker image ${{ github.event.repository.name }}:${{ steps.variables.outputs.commitSha }}"
        if: steps.image_checker.outputs.shouldBuildNewImage == 0
        run: |
          docker pull ${{ steps.variables.outputs.dockerRepositoryUrl }}:${{ steps.variables.outputs.commitSha }}
```

When the step is skipped, it still appears in the logs, but grayed out and in my scenario, the text doesn't show the 'image:tag' getting pulled

Comment: The goal for me really was to use Github actions as a CI/CD orchestrator, but not a build orchestrator (see  [this article](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2016/02/28/separation-of-concerns-application-builds-continuous-integration/)).  I do want to see my build steps easily, but I don't want to have to hard wire my pipeline to my build steps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to group the logs inside the build step.

```
jobs:
  bash-example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Group of log lines
        run: |
            echo "::group::My title"
            echo "Inside group"
            echo "::endgroup::"
```

[image: Grouping]

Documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#grouping-log-lines

Pretty late to the party, but hope someone find it useful